# Get selected item with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with attributes and I'm trying to select a certain one on load.

Each of my attributes have attribute object, type object and an array of attributeValues.

I want to select the attribute value with chosen=true

**Here's my Angular code:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.profileData = { "attributes": [{
        "attribute": {
            "id": 56,
                "name": "Hárlitur",
                "typeID": 5,
                "visibleToUsers": true
        },
            "type": {
            "id": 5,
                "typeName": "list"
        },
            "attributeValues": [{
            "id": 109,
                "attributeID": 56,
                "value": "Ljós",
                "chosen": true
        }, {
            "id": 110,
                "attributeID": 56,
                "value": "Dökkur",
                "chosen": false
        }],
            "valueText": null
    }]};

    $scope.changeValue = function changeValue(attribute, value) {
            alert(JSON.stringify({"attributeID":attribute.attribute.id, "type": attribute.type.typeName, "value":value.id}));
    };
});
```

**Here's my HTML code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in profileData.attributes">
        <select ng-change="changeValue(attribute, attributeValue)" ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in attribute.attributeValues" ng-model="attributeValue.id"></select>
</div>
```

**Here's my plunker:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/VMbmSB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution to your problem, but it works.

What I ddid was to simply create a function to search for the chosen value set as true. Upon finding that value I set the scope model as that attribute value. Then I called that function immediately afterwards.

```
$scope.selectChosen = function selectChosen() {
    var attrVals = $scope.profileData.attributes[0].attributeValues;
    for (var i = 0; i < attrVals.length; i++) {
        if (attrVals[i].chosen) {
            $scope.attributeValue = attrVals[i];
            break;
        }
    }
};
$scope.selectChosen();
```

The complete plunker is at: http://plnkr.co/edit/UcmQ8Q?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I found a better Angular-ish solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in profileData.attributes">
    <select ng-model="attributeValue" ng-change="changeValue(attribute, attributeValue)">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="obj in attribute.attributeValues" value="{{obj.id}}" ng-selected="obj.chosen">{{obj.value}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```